# Como executar uma função apenas quando for imprimir a pagina?

Tags: jquery, impressão

Ola, bom eu tenho uma função para corrigir o BUG do chrome quando se coloca uma tabela para imprimir.

- OBS: para quem não sabe este bug é que o  da tabela não é replico nas paginas seguintes, diferentes de outros navegadores.*

bom, eis que consigo o script para corrigir o bug, porem gostaria de deixar a função que corrige o bug apenas quando for imprimir.

**Então gostaria de saber se no Jquery eu consigo criar uma função para chamar outra apenas quando for imprimir.. tipo um window.print(function(){**

Comment: Douglas, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Mesmo que você pudesse executar um Script para alterar o que é impresso não há meiow (e mesmo que houvesse seria algo de extrema complexidade) para calcular posições e redistribuir os elementos na saída para incluir os cabeçalhos em cada página.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, parece que você pode fazer isso através dos `matchMedia`.

```
var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
        // Meu script antes da impressão
    } else {
      // Depois da impressão
    }
})
```